# Testing Facebook sdk 4 doesn't run

Tags: php, facebook

I've been following this tutorial https://www.apptic.me/blog/simple-facebook-php-sdk-4-tutorial.php and i have my code exactly like right there with my own app id and secret. But i can't make my app to show the pic, when i clic on "Login" it returns to the same page in a loop. I have already set the "App Domains" and already set "Site URL". My Server is runing php 5.4.

Thanks in Advance!

here the code!

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once('Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('Facebook/GraphUser.php');
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

$app_id = 'xxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxx';

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id, $app_secret);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Facebook SDK example</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper("http://herbalista.hol.es/apps/herbalista/index.php", $app_id, $app_secret);
try {
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}
catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) { }
catch(\Exception $ex) { }

catch(\Exception $ex) { }

$loggedIn = false;

if (isset($session)){
if ($session) {
$loggedIn = true;
try {
// Logged in
$user_photos = (new FacebookRequest(
$session, 'GET', '/me/photos/uploaded'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
$user_photos = $user_photos->asArray();
$pic = $user_photos["data"][0]->{"source"};
//print_r($user_photos);
echo "<img src='$pic' />";
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
}
}
}
if (!$loggedIn){
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('user_photos'));
echo "<a href='$loginUrl'>Login";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my serverver returns "Other (session) request error: couldn't connect to host"

Answer (score 0):

I already find the problem. My free host deactivate this functionn. Thanks